# Angular 2 default route when base href not root

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have these routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'Home', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/Home', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }, 
];
```

and base href set like this:

```
<base href="/Site1/" />
```

When I navigate to localhost/Site1 I get the NotFound component, when I was expecting it to redirect to /Home

If I try localhost/Site1/ (with trailing forward slash) it does match the default route and redirects to /Home

How can I get the first URL to redirect properly?

Comment: Just remove slash after Site1 like this  <base href="/Site1" />

Comment: I tired that but it doesn't help, same problem occurs

Comment: Dont you use any port? like 3000 or 4200? And have you implemented HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: Also having exact same problem, did you find any reason why it works like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You add extra `/` in your route definitions

```
    const routes: Routes = [
            { path: 'Home', component: DashboardComponent },
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //        removed the extra slash in the below line 
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },  
            { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }, 
        ];
```

Comment: No, this didn't help either

Comment: same as before, it is routing to the NotFound component - the ** route

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround than a fix I make it work by replacing :

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

with :

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
```